# How to get text not in the autocomplete list using jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
   var options = {
       select: function(event,ui) {

         searchIndex = $.inArray(ui.item.value, arrayA)
   },
   source: function(req, response) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(reg, term);
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re + "i");
        response($.grep(arrayA, function(item, index) {
        return matcher.test(item);
    })); 
  }
```

};

Given the autocomplete options listed above, how do I get the text not listed in the array list (arrayA) but is typed in the input text area after entering the enter key?

```
  <input type=text id="searchAText" />
```

Comment: please be more specific what you want to access and what you want to do with it

Comment: all is working if getting text from the array list in the autocomplete, but when I type in text that is not in the array list and hit the enter key, nothing happens as it should be but in my case I need to alert this text that is not in the array list...

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking for but if you want to continue typing if there is no suggestion, then there might be some problem with that code usually if there is no suggestion and you press space then you should be able to type the text as usual. Go to http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and click source, you will find the basic code that works like how you asked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get text from the input text area when autocomplete is close using jquery ui?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790432/how-to-get-text-from-the-input-text-area-when-autocomplete-is-close-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is old topic. But I also had a need to find out the value outside the list.

I succeeded when I used the change event instead of select event, and checked if ui.item is null and if it is value is in $(this).val().

So in your case, it would be about like this :

```
change: function(event,ui) {
    if (ui.item == null)
    searchIndex = $.inArray($(this).val(), arrayA);
    else
    searchIndex = $.inArray(ui.item.value, arrayA);
},
```