# How to get text from the input text area when autocomplete is close using jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Jquery UI autocomplete opens when you typed a letter in the input text area that matches a list of selections of the source object and close after making a selection from the list of selections using the enter key or close if the text you typed in is not in the list of selections.

How do I check when the autocomplete closed after typing text that is not in the list of selections? What I'm trying to do is when the enter key is enter, check if the autocomplete is closed, and if so, get the text in the text area if its not empty.

Something like this:

```
           $(".inputText").keydown(function()
           {
               if(keyChar == enterKey)
               {
                 // Somehow check is autocomplete is closed and if inputText is not empty, get the text without it interfering with the autocomplete select event. 
               }

           });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are, broadly, two approaches, one bound to the element via the `autocomplete()` method, the second listening for a custom event, `autocompleteclose`, fired by the closure of the auto-complete list:

```
var list = [
    'apple',
    'Azerbaijan',
    'aggregate',
    'Albert',
    'Aunty',
    'admissible',
    'and so forth...'
];

$('#textInput').autocomplete({
    source: list,
    close: function ( event, ui ) {
        var v = this.value;
        if (list.indexOf(v) === -1) {
            list.push(v);
        }
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rEmWs/).

Or:

```
$('#textInput').on('autocompleteclose', function (event, ui) {
    var v = this.value;
    if (list.indexOf(v) === -1) {
        list.push(v);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rEmWs/1).

References:

- [`autocomplete()` method's `close` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-close).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, what you are looking for is the "select" attribute of the auto complete.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: aTags,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        alert(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

Here the JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CezarisLT/KHqQm/